# 0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0x0000000000000000. c++

Tags: c++, direct3d

I'm having a very annoying issue for something I'm working on. I've tried numerous solutions and researching this error doesnt help solve my exact issue. Is anyone able to help? I've included my Overlay.cpp below...

```
#include "Overlay.h"

Overlay::Overlay() {
m_hWnd = NULL;
m_hGame = NULL;

m_pDirect3D = nullptr;
m_pDevice = nullptr;

memset(&m_Present, NULL, sizeof(D3DPRESENT_PARAMETERS));
}

Overlay::~Overlay() {
if (m_pDevice) {
    m_pDevice->Release();
    m_pDevice = nullptr;
}

if (m_pDirect3D) {
    m_pDirect3D->Release();
    m_pDirect3D = nullptr;
}
}

bool Overlay::Attach(HWND hWnd) {
m_hGame = hWnd;

if (!m_hGame) {
    return false;
}

RECT client;

GetClientRect(m_hGame, &client);

m_nSize[0] = client.right;
m_nSize[1] = client.bottom;

WNDCLASSEX wc = { NULL };

wc.cbSize           = sizeof(WNDCLASSEX);
wc.style            = CS_VREDRAW | CS_HREDRAW;
wc.lpfnWndProc      = WndProcedure;
wc.cbClsExtra       = NULL;
wc.cbWndExtra       = NULL;
wc.hInstance        = NULL;
wc.hIcon            = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);
wc.hCursor          = LoadCursor(NULL, IDC_ARROW);
wc.hbrBackground    = (HBRUSH)COLOR_WINDOW;
wc.lpszMenuName     = NULL;
wc.lpszClassName    = OVERLAY_NAME;
wc.hIconSm          = LoadIcon(NULL, IDI_APPLICATION);

if (!RegisterClassEx(&wc)) {
    return false;
}

m_hWnd = CreateWindowEx(WS_EX_TOPMOST | WS_EX_COMPOSITED | WS_EX_TRANSPARENT | WS_EX_LAYERED, OVERLAY_NAME, OVERLAY_NAME, WS_POPUP, CW_USEDEFAULT, CW_USEDEFAULT, m_nSize[0], m_nSize[1], NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);

if (!m_hWnd) {
    return false;
}

MARGINS margin = { -1, -1, -1, -1 };

DwmExtendFrameIntoClientArea(m_hWnd, &margin);

ShowWindow(m_hWnd, SW_SHOWDEFAULT);

UpdateWindow(m_hWnd);

RECT game;

GetWindowRect(m_hGame, &game);

RECT cl;

GetClientRect(m_hGame, &cl);

int w = game.right - game.left;
int h = game.bottom - game.top;

LONG_PTR dwStyle = GetWindowLongPtr(m_hGame, GWL_STYLE);

if (dwStyle & WS_BORDER) {
    int x = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CXBORDER);
    int y = GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYCAPTION) + GetSystemMetrics(SM_CYBORDER);

    game.left += x;
    game.top += y;

    w -= x;
    h -= y;
}

MoveWindow(m_hWnd, game.left, game.top, w, h, TRUE);

m_nSize[0] = w;
m_nSize[1] = h;

return InitDirectX();
}

int Overlay::OnFrame() {
MSG msg;

while (true) {
    Sleep(1);

    if (PeekMessage(&msg, NULL, NULL, NULL, PM_REMOVE)) {
        if (msg.message == WM_QUIT) {
            break;
        }

        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessageA(&msg);
    } else {
        m_pDevice->Clear(NULL, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, NULL, 1.0f, NULL);
        m_pDevice->BeginScene();

        if (!m_pOnFrameList.empty()) {
            for (auto& pOnFrame : m_pOnFrameList) {
                if (pOnFrame) {
                    pOnFrame();
                }
            }
        }

        m_pDevice->EndScene();
        m_pDevice->Present(NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL);
    }
}

return (int)msg.wParam;
}

void Overlay::AddOnFrame(const OnFrameFn& pFunction) {
m_pOnFrameList.push_back(pFunction);
}

void Overlay::GetScreenSize(int* width, int* height) {
if (width) {
    *width = m_nSize[0];
}

if (height) {
    *height = m_nSize[1];
}
}

IDirect3DDevice9* Overlay::GetDevice() const {
return m_pDevice;
}

bool Overlay::InitDirectX() {
m_Present.EnableAutoDepthStencil    = TRUE;
m_Present.AutoDepthStencilFormat    = D3DFMT_D16;
m_Present.Windowed                  = TRUE;
m_Present.BackBufferCount           = 1;
m_Present.BackBufferFormat          = D3DFMT_A8R8G8B8;
m_Present.BackBufferWidth           = m_nSize[0];
m_Present.BackBufferHeight          = m_nSize[1];
m_Present.MultiSampleType           = D3DMULTISAMPLE_NONE;
m_Present.SwapEffect                = D3DSWAPEFFECT_DISCARD;
m_Present.PresentationInterval      = D3DPRESENT_INTERVAL_IMMEDIATE;
m_Present.hDeviceWindow             = m_hWnd;

m_pDirect3D = Direct3DCreate9(D3D_SDK_VERSION);

if (!m_pDirect3D) {
    return false;
}

if (FAILED(m_pDirect3D->CreateDevice(D3DADAPTER_DEFAULT, D3DDEVTYPE_HAL, m_hWnd, D3DCREATE_HARDWARE_VERTEXPROCESSING, &m_Present, &m_pDevice))) {
    return false;
}

if (!m_pDevice) {
    return false;
}

return true;
}

LRESULT WINAPI Overlay::WndProcedure(HWND hWnd, UINT message, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam) {
switch (message) {
case WM_DESTROY:
    PostQuitMessage(NULL);
    break;

default:
    return DefWindowProc(hWnd, message, wParam, lParam);
}

return NULL;
}
```

My error occurs at this line `m_pDevice->Clear(NULL, NULL, D3DCLEAR_TARGET, NULL, 1.0f, NULL);`

Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: You're passing NULL as a parameter that expects a pointer to memory.

Comment: And what did the debugger tell you ?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: Check the value of `m_pDevice` at the time of the error. afaict from the code in your question, it always has the same _undesirable_ value.

Answer (score 2):

NULL means 0x0.
So probably you are passing NULL to m_pDevice->Clear() where its going to be read.

Additionally, make sure that m_pDevice is not nullptr.